# How do I measure the read/write speed of a hard drive in a RAID5 array?

Tags: raid, hard-drive, software-raid

I have created a 3-drive Linux RAID5 (md) array out of brand new Seagate Barracuda drives. I can measure the performance of the whole array by using: `ioping -s 8k -c 10 -D -W .`, where the current directory is backed by a RAID device (`/dev/md1`). Is there any way I can measure the IO performance (not only read, but also write) off the individual drives, e.g., `/dev/sda1`, etc, without damaging the filesystem?

Comment: Please do not use RAID5 if data is of any importance to you.

Comment: I agree with @TeroKilkanen, a three drive RAID5 has the capacity of 2x one drive.  A three drive RAID1E has 1.5x the capacity of one drive.  With all the downsides to RAID5, It hardly seems worth it.  But, a half-answer to your question: you can benchmark with full stripe writes.  If you do that, there shouldn't be any reading going on.  Other than that, there aren't any good options.  You can fail a drive out and do your benchmarking on it.  Wipe the drive before putting it back in to make absolutely sure you don't recover from the bitmap.